Convert tikz (in tikzit) code to a graph in Mathematica
I want to convert a TikZ graph from TikZiT into a graph in Mathematica. I want to retain the vertices, edges, and the positions of the vertices. As for the color of the vertices or the style of the edges, I don't need to worry about that for now. Then I used the code written by GPT (with some minor adjustments on my part). When the edge style is not set, everything works fine.
The information of a graph in TikZIt is explained as follows.
\node [style=square] (1) at (10, -10) {};

The node, named 1, is located at (10, -10).
\draw [style=blackedge] (5) to (11);

or
 \draw  (5) to (11);

This means an egde (5,11) (edge style is like to style=..).
A graph code is stored in test.tikz:
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=square] (1) at (10, -10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (2) at (5.29412, -3.33333) {};
        \node [style=square] (3) at (10, 10) {};
        \node [style=square] (4) at (-10, -10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (5) at (3.33333, -5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (6) at (2.54902, -1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (7) at (5.29412, 3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (8) at (3.33333, 5.29412) {};
        \node [style=square] (9) at (-10, 10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (10) at (-5.29412, -3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (11) at (-3.33333, -5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (12) at (1.37255, -2.54902) {};
        \node [style=square] (13) at (0.980392, -0.980392) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (14) at (2.54902, 1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (15) at (1.37255, 2.54902) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (16) at (-3.33333, 5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (17) at (-5.29412, 3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (18) at (-2.54902, -1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (19) at (-1.37255, -2.54902) {};
        \node [style=square] (20) at (-0.980392, -0.980392) {};
        \node [style=square] (21) at (0.980392, 0.980392) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (22) at (-1.37255, 2.54902) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (23) at (-2.54902, 1.37255) {};
        \node [style=square] (24) at (-0.980392, 0.980392) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw (1) to (2);
        \draw (1) to (3);
        \draw (1) to (4);
        \draw (1) to (5);
        \draw (2) to (5);
        \draw (2) to (6);
        \draw (2) to (7);
        \draw (3) to (7);
        \draw (3) to (8);
        \draw (3) to (9);
        \draw (4) to (9);
        \draw (4) to (10);
        \draw (4) to (11);
        \draw (5) to (11);
        \draw (5) to (12);
        \draw (6) to (12);
        \draw (6) to (13);
        \draw (6) to (14);
        \draw (7) to (8);
        \draw (7) to (14);
        \draw (8) to (15);
        \draw (8) to (16);
        \draw (9) to (16);
        \draw (9) to (17);
        \draw (10) to (11);
        \draw (10) to (17);
        \draw (10) to (18);
        \draw (11) to (19);
        \draw (12) to (13);
        \draw (12) to (19);
        \draw (13) to (20);
        \draw (13) to (21);
        \draw (14) to (15);
        \draw (14) to (21);
        \draw (15) to (21);
        \draw (15) to (22);
        \draw (16) to (17);
        \draw (16) to (22);
        \draw (17) to (23);
        \draw (18) to (19);
        \draw (18) to (20);
        \draw (18) to (23);
        \draw (19) to (20);
        \draw (20) to (24);
        \draw (21) to (24);
        \draw (22) to (23);
        \draw (22) to (24);
        \draw (23) to (24);
        \draw (16) to (15);
        \draw (8) to (22);
        \draw (17) to (22);
        \draw (16) to (23);
        \draw (23) to (10);
        \draw (17) to (18);
        \draw (18) to (11);
        \draw (10) to (19);
        \draw (19) to (5);
        \draw (12) to (11);
        \draw (6) to (5);
        \draw (12) to (2);
        \draw (2) to (14);
        \draw (7) to (6);
        \draw (15) to (7);
        \draw (8) to (14);
        \draw (22) to (21);
        \draw (15) to (24);
        \draw (24) to (13);
        \draw (21) to (20);
        \draw (20) to (12);
        \draw (13) to (19);
        \draw (23) to (20);
        \draw (24) to (18);
        \draw (13) to (14);
        \draw (6) to (21);
        \draw (9) to (10);
        \draw (17) to (4);
        \draw (4) to (5);
        \draw (11) to (1);
        \draw (1) to (7);
        \draw (3) to (2);
        \draw (9) to (8);
        \draw (16) to (3);
        \draw (4) to (3);
        \draw (9) to (1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

ImportTikZGraph[file_String] := 
 Module[{tikzCode, lines, nodes, edges, line, parts, nodeID, xCoord, 
   yCoord, startNode, endNode, 
   g},(*Import the TikZ code from the file*)
  tikzCode = Import[file, "Text"];
  (*Initialize lists for nodes and edges*)nodes = {};
  edges = {};
  (*Split the TikZ code into lines*)
  lines = StringSplit[tikzCode, "\n"];
  (*Extract node information*)
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[lines], i++, line = StringTrim[lines[[i]]];
   If[StringStartsQ[line, "\\node"],(*Extract node ID and coordinates*)
    parts = StringCases[line, 
      "\\node [" ~~ ___ ~~ "] (" ~~ nodeID : DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
        ") at (" ~~ x : (DigitCharacter | "." | "-" | "E") .. ~~ 
        ", " ~~ y : (DigitCharacter | "." | "-" | "E") .. ~~ 
        ") {};" :> {nodeID, x, y}];
    If[Length[parts] > 0, nodeID = ToExpression[parts[[1, 1]]];
     xCoord = ToExpression[parts[[1, 2]]];
     yCoord = ToExpression[parts[[1, 3]]];
     AppendTo[nodes, nodeID -> {xCoord, yCoord}];];];];
  (*Extract edge information*)
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[lines], i++, line = StringTrim[lines[[i]]];
   If[StringStartsQ[line, 
     "\\draw"],(*Extract the start and end nodes of edges*)
    parts = StringCases[line, 
      "\\draw (" ~~ startNode : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ") to (" ~~ 
        endNode : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ");" :> {startNode, endNode}];
    If[Length[parts] > 0, startNode = ToExpression[parts[[1, 1]]];
     endNode = ToExpression[parts[[1, 2]]];
     AppendTo[edges, UndirectedEdge[startNode, endNode]];];];];
  (*Create the graph from extracted edges and node positions*)
  g = Graph[edges, VertexCoordinates -> nodes, 
    VertexStyle -> GrayLevel[1], VertexSize -> Medium];
  (*Return the graph*)g]

graph = ImportTikZGraph["test.tikz"]



However, when I set the edge styles, it seems to fail. I've tried a few times.
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=square] (1) at (10, -10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (2) at (5.29412, -3.33333) {};
        \node [style=square] (3) at (10, 10) {};
        \node [style=square] (4) at (-10, -10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (5) at (3.33333, -5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (6) at (2.54902, -1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (7) at (5.29412, 3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (8) at (3.33333, 5.29412) {};
        \node [style=square] (9) at (-10, 10) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (10) at (-5.29412, -3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (11) at (-3.33333, -5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (12) at (1.37255, -2.54902) {};
        \node [style=square] (13) at (0.980392, -0.980392) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (14) at (2.54902, 1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (15) at (1.37255, 2.54902) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (16) at (-3.33333, 5.29412) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (17) at (-5.29412, 3.33333) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (18) at (-2.54902, -1.37255) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (19) at (-1.37255, -2.54902) {};
        \node [style=square] (20) at (-0.980392, -0.980392) {};
        \node [style=square] (21) at (0.980392, 0.980392) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (22) at (-1.37255, 2.54902) {};
        \node [style=whitenode] (23) at (-2.54902, 1.37255) {};
        \node [style=square] (24) at (-0.980392, 0.980392) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [style=blackedge] (1) to (2);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (1) to (3);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (1) to (4);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (1) to (5);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (2) to (5);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (2) to (6);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (2) to (7);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (3) to (7);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (3) to (8);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (3) to (9);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (4) to (9);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (4) to (10);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (4) to (11);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (5) to (11);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (5) to (12);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (6) to (12);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (6) to (13);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (6) to (14);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (7) to (8);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (7) to (14);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (8) to (15);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (8) to (16);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (9) to (16);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (9) to (17);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (10) to (11);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (10) to (17);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (10) to (18);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (11) to (19);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (12) to (13);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (12) to (19);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (13) to (20);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (13) to (21);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (14) to (15);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (14) to (21);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (15) to (21);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (15) to (22);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (16) to (17);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (16) to (22);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (17) to (23);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (18) to (19);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (18) to (20);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (18) to (23);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (19) to (20);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (20) to (24);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (21) to (24);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (22) to (23);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (22) to (24);
        \draw [style=blackedge] (23) to (24);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (16) to (15);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (8) to (22);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (17) to (22);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (16) to (23);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (23) to (10);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (17) to (18);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (18) to (11);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (10) to (19);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (19) to (5);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (12) to (11);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (6) to (5);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (12) to (2);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (2) to (14);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (7) to (6);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (15) to (7);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (8) to (14);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (22) to (21);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (15) to (24);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (24) to (13);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (21) to (20);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (20) to (12);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (13) to (19);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (23) to (20);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (24) to (18);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (13) to (14);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (6) to (21);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (9) to (10);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (17) to (4);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (4) to (5);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (11) to (1);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (1) to (7);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (3) to (2);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (9) to (8);
        \draw [style=blueedge] (16) to (3);
        \draw [style=blueedge, bend left=60, looseness=2.25] (4) to (3);
        \draw [style=blueedge, bend left=60, looseness=2.25] (9) to (1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

It looks the following:


In what it fails?

If some edge like \draw [style=blackedge]…, the edge cannot be recognized.

I added answer that works also with the second input.

(* strg is string of OP "\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]..."*)

vc = ToExpression@
   StringCases[strg, 
    Shortest["\\node " ~~ ___ ~~ "("] ~~ Shortest[n__] ~~ ") at (" ~~ 
      Shortest[x__] ~~ "," ~~ Shortest[y__] ~~ ")" :> {n, {x, y}}];
ed = ToExpression@
   StringCases[strg, 
    Shortest["\\draw " ~~ ___ ~~ "("] ~~ Shortest[n1__] ~~ ") to (" ~~
       Shortest[n2__] ~~ ")" :> {n1, n2}];

Graph[vc[[All, 1]], ed, VertexCoordinates -> vc[[All, 2]]]



